# Double VPN not working

Tags: iptables, vpn, routing, openvpn, forwarding

I have setup OpenVpn in my raspberry pi and it works correctly, I can log in to my raspberry pi from my cellphone. I also installed a paid VPN (Windscribe) to my raspberry pi too. The problem comes when I activate my paid vpn (windscribe) with `windscribe connect` In my raspberry pi.
After that I can no longer reach my raspberry with my cellphone.

I want OpenVPN(PiVPN) so I can access my home network, and I want windscribe vpn also active to safetly browse internet. Right now I have the first part. I can access my home network when windscribe is not active.

I've been trying a lot with the iptables with no success, crating forward rules for interfaces, tunnels, and a lot of combinations, but nothing seems to work. At the end I reset everything.

here are my configurations.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o wlan0 -m comment --comment openvpn-nat-rule -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT DROP
-A OUTPUT ! -o tun+ -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT ! -o tun+ -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 104.20.26.217/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 104.20.27.217/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 172.67.17.175/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 104.21.93.29/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 172.67.203.127/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 104.21.53.216/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 172.67.219.39/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 172.67.189.40/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 104.21.65.74/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 209.58.129.121/32 -j ACCEPT

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.111  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether b8:27:eb:ec:6a:4b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 19989  bytes 21885907 (20.8 MiB)
        RX errors 160  dropped 4  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11508  bytes 1206589 (1.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 618  bytes 201828 (197.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 618  bytes 201828 (197.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.0.1
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun1: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.120.138.29  netmask 255.255.254.0  destination 10.120.138.29
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 164  bytes 32755 (31.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 961  bytes 114896 (112.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:b9:3f:1e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip route list
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.120.138.1 dev tun1
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.0.111 metric 202
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1
10.120.138.0/23 dev tun1 proto kernel scope link src 10.120.138.29
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.120.138.1 dev tun1
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.111 metric 202
209.58.129.121 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip rule list
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

UPDATE:
I found this tutorial, and it helped me alot comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/raspberry-pi-vpn .
But I found that when I set this 2 rules

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.2 lookup 101 
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 table 101
```

I can access the vpn but I can no longer ping my vpn server like before with 192.168.0.111, Now I have to use 10.8.0.1. Any Ideas how to enable ping to 192.168.0.111 – tseres 12 mins ago   Delete

Comment: And where do you activate your *windscribe* vpn? Cell phone or RPI?

Comment: In the raspberry pi, I edited my original post.

Comment: So in case of your cell phone RPi works as OpenVPN server and in case of itself with *windscribe* it works as VPN client. Right? Anyway, the issue is that after you activate *windscribe* it creates more prioritized default route `0.0.0.0/1` which would make *reply* packets of new cell phone VPN connection to go into *windscribe* tunnel. IIUC probably you could run `tcpdump` in `tmux` on your *eth0* while connecting your cell phone, you should be returning traffic on *eth0*, then connect RPi to *windscribe* run `tcpdump` again and you should see incomming cell phone traffic but not returning.

Comment: If I was right and you want to keep such setup, maybe you could trigger somehow creation of new static route for your cell phone (public IP) so it would be returning via *192.168.0.1* and not *windscribe* default route.

Comment: Any update? I'm really curious how is this solved :)

Comment: yes, I found this tutorial, and it helped me alot https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/raspberry-pi-vpn/ . But I found that when I set this 2 rules `ip rule add from 192.168.1.2 lookup 101`
`ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 table 101` I can access the vpn but I can no longer ping my vpn server like before with 192.168.0.111, Now I have to use 10.8.0.1. Any Ideas how to enable ping to 192.168.0.111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to make it work. thanks to https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=251453&sid=5d7e57949fb3cec559d5319f666f3825#p1638481

by replacing these lines

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.2 lookup 101 
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 table 101
```

with

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --sport 1194 -j MARK --set-mark 1
sudo ip rule add fwmark 1 table 101
sudo ip route add table 101 default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
```

Explanation:
The first line marks all packets coming from OpenVPN server on port 1194 - you will need to change this number if you are listening on something else. This also stops the default routes from taking over and pushing tun-incoming straight out tun-outgoing and causing asymmetric routing.
The second line, is an IP policy rule that says if the packet is marked with a '1' then lookup the route table 101.
The third line is a route rule that makes the packets route out eth0 back to the broadband router, back to the mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Is your raspberry PI in a private network ? Like at home with an internet Box ? Then it's not working because you have to add routes in your private network from your internet box to your raspberry PI. Then with your cellphone conected to your public VPN, try to reach to the public IP of your internetBox.

If your cellphone is connected to an external VPN with a public IP and your raspeberry PI is in a private network they can't reach themselves. The first thing you have to do is to make the VPN of your rapsberry PI reachable by the public network. 
I hope it can help, it's very hard to connect two different VPN, why are you doing it this way ? (no offence I'm just wondering)

A simpler solution would be to get the public IP of your external VPN and then on your local router allow ssh or whatever protocol from this IP to be redirected to your raspberry.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply I think I didnt express corretly my setup. the raspberry pi has PiVPN and WindscribeVPN installed. my cellphone has Openvpn to connect to my raspberry Pi. Without Windscribe active in my raspberry pi the connection is a success but when I activate windscribe I can no longer reach my raspberry pi

Comment: So you want to have two vpn simultaneously on your raspebrry PI (PiVPN and WindscribeVPN) and then choose wich one to connect to with your cellphone ?

Comment: No, I want PiVPN so I can access my home network, and I want windscribe vpn also active to safetly browse internet